# Query all pages including subpages of child pages in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have following structure

```
Services
  -Page_1
  -Page_2
     --Page_3
     --Page_4
```

I use Wp-query to get pages. This is my args:

```
  <?php $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'page',
       'post_parent' => '45'
 ); ?>
```

45 is ID of Services page.
But I only get first level Page_1 and Page_2. How do I get all pages? I'm using Advanced Custom Fields plugin so using get_pages() is not a good option, is it?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13669/using-the-loop-to-show-all-levels-of-subpages-under-a-parent-page-halfway-there)?

Comment: Why is `get_pages` not a good option with ACF? You should still be able to get all the required post meta once you get the page id? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Frits No, you are right, get_pages() with ACF is a legit option. ACF can work with page ids.

Comment: In that case, I can give you a get_pages() solution if you'd like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in your comments, the easiest solutions is to actually use [`get_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pages/). You can still grab meta data of posts if you are able to get the the ID of the page (which you  can with `get_pages()`) so you should still be able to ACF's custom fields.

Here's an example of `get_pages()`:

```
$args = array(
    'child_of' => 45,
    'post_type' => 'page',
); 
$pages = get_pages($args);
```

The main difference between `get_pages()` and `WP_Query` that we want to focus on here is the `'child-of'=>45` paramater vs the `'post_parent'=>45`.

The `child-of` argument will grab ALL children throughout the hierarchy, i.e. children and children's children etc.

In contrast, the `post-parent` argument of `WP_Query` will only grab **direct** children of the page.

---

## Using in conjunction with ACF

If you need to grab custom fields from ACF, you will still be able to use [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/).

If your custom field includes an array of values, you will need to unserialize it first and then loop through the values like this:

```
$meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'acf_meta_key', true ); //grab the post meta using WordPress core function
$array = unserialize( $meta ); //unserialize the field into an array
foreach ( $array as $value ) { //loop through the array
    echo $value .'<br>'; 
}
```